# What does the letter "y" mean in the TTY command?

Tags: abbreviations

In Linux, **the TTY command** prints the file name of the terminal connected to standard input.

Maybe the first *"t"* means "*terminal*", the second "*t*" means "*to of connected to*", but what does the letter "*y*" mean here?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for/482244

Comment: -1 what makes you think this is a question about learning English?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is veering right off the topic of learning the English language.

Comment: If asking about [the meaning of **^^**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86629/what-does-this-mean)  is on topic, I don't see how asking about an actual English acronym, word  or abbreviation is off topic! I actually learned some English (and history) from this question. @NathanTuggy et al.

Comment: If you Google search "TTY", there are two Wikipedia articles at the very top that answer this question. This could have been answered with a bit of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of TTY in Unix is from teletype terminals [Source - Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5421/what-is-the-concept-behind-tty-in-linux)

However for future reference, this probably is out of the scope of ELL (or even English Language and Usage) as it requires too much specialist knowledge.

Comment: Thus **T**ele**TY**pe. See also Wikipedia on [the teletype](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter) or teleprinter.

Comment: Answering a question that's out of scope is ... not that great an idea.